# Why do journals have limits on the number of references?

Tags: publications, citations, journals

I was rather shocked when hearing in a conversation that journals sometimes have explicit limits on the number of references that can be included in one article. I understand that there are space concerns for print publications, and that word/page limits, as well as limits on the numbers of figures and tables are common. But placing limits on the number of references strike me as rather close to impinging on the integrity of the articles themselves (would anyone support a motion to limit the number of authors?).

**Question**: What are some reasons that have led journals to limit the number of references?

*Clarification*: I am not asking whether this is a good idea in general. (I think it is silly, but that's just my opinion.) I am not asking whether this can have some *potentially good effect* on the quality of scientific writing. I am specifically asking whether there was an official explanation ever issued on the part of the publishers explaining this rule, or whether there was some event (say, an abuse in the form of many gratuitous references or an observed trend for the average number of references to keep growing if not otherwise checked) or some strong personality (famous editor-in-chief X) that led to these kinds of policies being formulated.

For example, [*Applied Physics Letters*](http://publishing.aip.org/authors/journal-guidelines) has limits on number of words (with some conversion factor applied also to figures and tables), but (in my opinion, rightly) excludes the title, the author list, and the list of references from the limit.

For examples of journals (from various publishers) that have limits on number of references:

- [*Nature*](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/#a5.4) "strictly enforces" a limit of 50 for articles and 30 for letters. ([*Science*](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/gen_info.xhtml), I note, does not for research articles. For review articles the limit is 100.)
- [*Earth and Planetary Science Letters*](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/earth-and-planetary-science-letters/0012-821x/guide-for-authors#68000) limits to 50.
- [*Blood*](http://www.bloodjournal.org/page/authors/author-guide/article-types?sso-checked=true) "recommends" a limit of 100 references, though I don't know if this is a hard limit or not.
- [*Journal of Clinical Ontology*](http://jco.ascopubs.org/site/ifc/prepguide.xhtml#Reference_Instructions) limits to 10 for "correspondences" and a "suggested limit" of 150 for "research articles".
- [*Journal of Genetics*](http://www.springer.com/life+sciences/journal/12041) (more reasonably, in my opinion), have different limits for different types of articles. But notably for research and review articles there are no limit to references: the reference number limit applies to shorter submissions such as correspondence, commentary, or "research notes".

---

*Some additional information*:

(**TL;DR**: *Nature* put in their current policy sometime between the years 1986 and 1988, with no reference limits prior. Did something happen in the 80s?)

I went down to the library and looked at the old issues of *Nature* (not because I want to single them out, but because the library happen to have all the issues since the 20s available on the stacks). After some binary search I found that in [December 1986 the instructions to the authors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4wbw.jpg) don't mention a limit to references:

> GUIDE TO AUTHORS
>
> Authors should be aware of the diversity of *Nature*'s readership and should strive to be as widely understood as possible.
> **Review articles** should be accessible to the whole readership. Most are commissioned, but unsolicited reviews are welcome (in which case prior consultation with the office is desirable).
> **Scientific articles** are research reports whose conclusions are of general interest or which represent substantial advances of understanding. The text should not exceed 3,000 words and six displayed items (figures plus tables). The article should include an italic heading of about 50 words.
> **Letters to *Nature*** are ordinarily 1,000 words long with no more than four displayed items. The first paragraph (not exceeding 150 words) should say what the letter is about, why the study it reports was undertaken and what the conclusions are.
> **Matters arising** are brief comments (up to 500 words) on articles and letters recently published in *Nature*. The originator of a Matters Arising contribution should initially send his manuscript to the author of the original paper and both parties should, wherever possible, agree on what is to be submitted.

In [October 1988 the guidelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQFnl.jpg) it became almost the same as present day.

> GUIDE TO AUTHORS
>
> *Please follow these guidelines so that your manuscript may be handled expeditiously*.
> *Nature* is an international journal covering all the sciences. [...] Because of the competition for space, many of the papers submitted for publication cannot be accepted. For this reason, and because brevity is a great assistance to readers, papers should be as brief as is consistent with intelligibility. Please note that one printed page of *Nature*, without diagrams or other interruptions of the text, has fewer than 1,300 words.
>
> CATEGORIES OF PAPER
>
> **Review Articles** survey recent developments in a field. Most are commissioned, but suggestions are welcome in the form of a one-page synopsis addressed to the Reviews Coordinator. Length is negotiable in advance but must not exceed six pages of *Nature*.
> **Articles** are research reports whose conclusions are of general interest and which are sufficiently rounded to be a substantial advance in understanding. They should not have more than 3,000 words of text or more than six display items (figures and tables) and should not exceed more than five pages of *Nature*. [...] There should be fewer than 50 references.
> **Letters to Nature** are short reports of outstanding novel findings whose implications are general and important enough to be of interest to those outside the field. Letters should not have more than 1,000 words of text or more than four display items and should not occupy more than two pages of *Nature*. The first paragraph should describe, in not more than 150 words, the origins and chief conclusions of the study. Letters should not have subheadings or more than 30 references.

(I don't have the exact date of the switch, since only some of the issues in the library came from the original magazines; others came from bound reprints ordered from the publisher which stripped out pages like these. So in particular I found no "Guides to Authors" in the 1987 issues I had access to.)

Back in the 20s and 30s most of the items in *Nature* had no references whatsoever. By the 50s and 60s we start seeing articles more in the form of what we expect today, but the number of references are generally not too many. Even in the 70s and the 80s (before the change of rules) the majority of the articles do abide by the modern rules, with [occasional exceptions](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v282/n5734/abs/282105a0.html).

Comment: *would anyone support a motion to limit the number of authors?* **Yes**

Comment: In the dark ages, APL had a hard three page limit - it _had_ to fit in three pages so you learned to focus on the necessary, not the nice to have. Similarly, if you need more than 30 references for a Nature letter, frankly, you are doing something wrong. The reason good writing is hard is that you have to throw out everything that is not really really really needed. The journals that have decided on reference limits have done so with a conscious decision for a reason. That you do not agree with it is probably not their concern. From your comments below you do not see their side of it at all.

Comment: @JonCuster: "The journals that have decided on reference limits have done so with a conscious decision for a reason... From your comments below you do not see their side of it at all." That's why I asked the question. If you do see their side, educate me, please?

Comment: @JonCuster To be more precise: what is accomplished by an explicit limit on references that is _not_ accomplished by strict page limits of the old APL or the strict word limits that are already in place for most of the journals I mentioned above?

Comment: By its very nature, a letter should be highly focused. It is not a review article. The previous results of a few papers combined with several techniques lead to some good data with discussion pointing to a solid conclusion. I just looked through a sampling of some old APLs - I never exceeded 20 references.  Why? To get my point across I did not need to. Any more would have been unnecessary, and there just wasn't room to discuss how 30 papers contributed to mine.  And if you don't _need_ to reference a paper, than it is gratuitous. If you do need to, your paper will be longer than a letter.

Comment: @JonCuster: why are you so focused on APL and on letters? I note that APL doesn't currently have a limit on number of references at all; I used it as an example of a journal that has a limit on word count but not on reference count. Note also that _Nature_ but not _Science_ have a limit on the number of references for research articles. Clearly not every publisher perceives the reference limit for research articles as a necessity.

Comment: In fact, if most authors never exceed 20 references, a limit of 30 references is a _solution in search of a non-existent problem_. I am inclined to believe the policy was instituted because there actually was once a problem. The question is: what was it? Was there actually an observed upward creep in the number of references before the policy was instituted? Was there a big scandal concerning gratuitous references? Was there a famous complaint about the decline of the state of scientific writing?

Comment: Clearly you feel strongly about this.  I'm not sure why.  Also, clearly, certain journals feel the need to specify. The fact that you choose not to see any merit in the aspects I've mentioned indicates, to me, that you prefer to complain rather than attempt to understand.  In the big picture, you should not expect the world to behave as you wish it to. They have their reasons, whether you acknowledge it or not.

Comment: @JonCuster: Throughout this whole discussion you have asserted that they have their reasons. **I have never disputed that.** I don't feel strongly about the fact that journals have reference limits. I have never run against them and probably never will. I do, however, feel strongly about your comments which entirely mischaracterize my question and my motives. I refuse to believe, based on your words and your words alone, that journals instituted this policy just to help us write better. I am more inclined to believe that the journals instituted this policy because of problems of ...

Comment: ...gratuitous citations. But I have edited my question one hour ago to be extremely specific (in line with the Stack Exchange preference for factual answerable questions): if the worries are gratuitous citations, what led to this worry? I invite you to re-read [my previous comment](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47777/why-do-journals-have-limits-on-the-number-of-references?noredirect=1#comment110303_47777). // As an aside I found your comments highly demeaning, and I thank you to stick to the facts and stop casting aspersions based on imaginary intent.

Comment: @JonCuster: Admittedly, I find your reasoning a bit difficult to follow. References that are "not needed" (for understanding the article at hand, I presume) are not automatically something to remove, but something *beneficial*; they are an opportunity for interested readers to directly retrieve more information related to the article that these readers would otherwise have to search for themselves. Maybe things are somehow different for the letters you mention, but in general, as a reader, it seems contradictory to me that removing *topically fitting* references could *improve* a paper.

Comment: Fair enough.  I did focus on the lower limits mentioned for, e.g. Nature's letters (30), and Clinical Ontology (10 for correspondence). These types of papers really are different from a full-length research article. The letter journals (APL, PRL, ...) which got split out from their parent journals were supposed to be focused on one single topic which could be presented within the length limits. Clearly, Nature saw they needed to be specific - if you try to cover too much territory as evidenced by lots of references, your letter likely isn't very good by their standards.

Comment: There is a limit because they don't want people submitting a research article that looks like the Encyclopædia Britannica.

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question? Was there a sudden deluge of people submitting articles that look like encyclopedia entries? Is this something they cannot easily just deal with at the level of the managing editors without having an explicit number?

Comment: Where do you get '"strictly enforces" a limit of 50 for articles and 30 for letters' out of the displayed photographs. I must have missed that. All I can read is "should".

Comment: @user3697176: the quote "strictly enforces" comes from the _current_ guidelines (see fourth paragraph of [section 5.4](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/#a5.4)). The photograph is of the 1988 version which I said is "almost the same" (and not exactly the same) as the present day.

Comment: I am extremely frustrated by these kinds of policies, which unfortunately are common in the journals and conferences that I submit to. Typically the limits are enforced as  *maximum X page(s) of references*. **These restrictions serve absolutely no purpose whatsoever**. Gratuitous references would get caught during review and then removed. I have found myself in several situations where citing all relevant literature was simply impossible due to these ridiculous restrictions. Ironically, in most of these cases the reviewers then get mad because their paper happened to get cut from references.

Answer (score 9):

Journals aim to publish an organized set of articles of some approximate length in an attractive format.

**Journals set limits on the number of references to shape the form, format, and quality of the submitted articles.**

This organization is a good thing, in terms of disseminating scientific information. Given the limited space of one article, there is definitely some appropriate range for the number of *essential* and *useful* references that relate to the presented work.

This is less restrictive that it might sound, as these rules set by the journal are seldom hard limits. If you have good reason to include a couple of extra references, you can usually work with the editor to get them included.

Another reason to include limits is to try to encourage authors to examine references more closely, and to be more selective in their choices of what to include. Just as many journals have rules against gratuitous figures and tables (e.g. all figs must be referenced in the text), these limits are meant to discourage gratuitous inclusion of references that are not directly related to the discussion in the manuscript.

---

**In response to the expanded question:** "What happened in the 80's?" ...

The Science Citation Index was launched in 1964. With its growth and success, and the addition of other field-specific indices, it became possible to compute statistical journal and author comparisons (e.g. [Impact Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor)). This concerted effort to index citations made being cited in the work of others more important, and the use of numerous citations became much more common. The benefits of these author and journal metrics were much lauded during the 70's and 80's, but people were also increasingly aware that this arrangement was *vulnerable to abuse*, i.e. gaming the system by inflating citations. SCI grew to become Web of Knowledge, then Web of Science and along the way (1992) it was acquired by a large media company and today it's run by [Thomson-Reuters](http://thomsonreuters.com/en/about-us/company-history.html).

The question posed invites speculation; we can't know exactly what the owners and editors of the various scientific journals were thinking when they started implementing citation limits. However, I would hazard a guess that they realized gratuitous citations might be an issue, probably had a few bad apples, and decided that limits were a good idea to keep the quality of the submissions high.

Comment: Plenty of journals makes space recommendations without explicit mention of the number of references. For length considerations a simple "total word count" with references included can suffice.

Comment: And whether references are "essential and useful" should be delegated to the referees, and not decided by a computer based on an arbitrary number. Indeed, if the intent is for the quality of the articles, such concerns about the references being "essential" can be both included in the instructions to the authors and the referees in lieu of a numeric count.

Comment: @WillieWong : I certainly agree that referees and the editor should determine what should be included, but that doesn't preclude the application of some guidelines for the general form of an article.

Comment: +1 however for your last paragraph, even though I think that there are better ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @WillieWong Putting the onus on the referees to 'enforce a limit of references' is corralling cats after they've walked out the door. Setting out guidelines that (upon justified request can be excepted) guide the product _before_ submission, seems a better way to manage the system. I'm not saying I agree with limits on references, but _if_ there are going to be limits, guidance should be _before_ submission and not _after_.

Comment: @CGCampbell: guidance I agree with, but wording is important. It would be nice if instead just stating matter-of-factly that there is a reference limit, the instruction reads something like: "Please only include scientifically necessary references, typical research articles in this journal have between 10 and 40 citations, while typical letters have between 2 and 25." With the implication that if you are an "outlier", we will scrutinize it; and even if you are within the norm, you don't get carte blanche to fill up the reference section with crap.

Comment: @CGCampbell: in any case, the point of my question is something somewhat different.

Answer (score 1):

In the dim past (40+ years ago?), people had no idea how often one was cited... so there was scant motivation to generate gratuitous citations of oneself by trading gratuitous citations of others. There was no "citation index", etc.

From even longer past, there has not been too much tradition of careful acknowledgement of prior art, especially not of competing art, and not of historical antecedents, whether well-known or obscure. That is, "scholarship" has rarely been relevant to publishability or enhanced status. So, no *need* to have substantial bibliographies, since as much would be ignored as possible.

Maybe time to air out the quotation from a very well-known mathematician, to the effect (and I think it was not a joke) that if one didn't read other peoples' papers, one would not have to ever cite them...

So, in mathematics, the current style has "evolved" to only citing things "logically necessary". Rather unhelpful even to fairly-expert readers, but helping the readers is not the main goal... >:-(

Comment: In my (perhaps idealistic) opinion, helping readers (and thereby writing a better article) should be the main goal. Inflated citation counts may have some short-term benefits in terms of impact factor, but relevant high-quality citations are actually quite important leads for connecting research. I'm plenty cynical about some of the practices I see in the literature, but really it's up to all of us who participate in peer-review  and publishing to move these things in a positive direction if they are ever to improve.